# Bootstrap align text next to image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to align some text next to image but didn't succeeded. What I want is this to go next to image where is the white space.

```
<p>Text -1 </p>
<p>Text -2 </p>
<p>Text -3 </p>
<p>Text -4 </p>
```

Here is what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/scc7we9r/

Comment: Have you tried using `float: left` on the image?

Comment: Whit float left text is still under the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Edit:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scc7we9r/3/)

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="http://www.explore-usa.org/site/images/golden_gate.png" width='200' />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <p>Name: Name</p>
      <p>Text -1</p>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Surrounded the two objects (Image and Text) in another `container` and `col-xs` to accomplish sudo-floating.

Comment: I want only the paragraphs that are `text -1,2,3,4`. Whit <span> like you show me I get this http://jsfiddle.net/scc7we9r/3/

Comment: Yeah. So all of it then. 1 sec.

Comment: Won't be able to update further; work day done. Hope that helps thought!

Comment: Thank's. It gives me some ideas how to make it. p.s. Your jsfiddle is wrong I think?

Comment: I noticed that he didn't update his JSFiddle with this code. The code is all good.

Comment: Strange that on jsfiddle is work but on the host it doesn't work as expected. All text goes behind the image..

Comment: Sorry guys, my work day ended and I was busy last night. Didn't get a chance to update my JSFiddle Example. And to address your concern, it's because it's a fixed-width image; try playing with the `col-xs-*` sizes and see if that changes anything.